# Cannot cleanly delete symlinks

Tags: windows, ntfs, symbolic-link, windows-8.1-preview

**Problem:** When deleting a symbolic link, traces of it remain in the filesystem.

**Demonstration:**

- Use `MKLINK` to create a symlink pointing to `E:\test`
  [image: MKLINK]
- Resulting output of `DIR /AL /S C:\ | FIND "SYMLINKD"`:
  [image: DIR output]
- Delete symlink (I just deleted the folder/shortcut in AppData using Windows Explorer)
- Output of `DIR /AL /S C:\ | FIND "SYMLINKD"` after deleting symlink:
  [image: Resulting DIR output after deleting symlink]

I expected the entry to be completely gone. Instead it is still there, only instead of the folder name, there is an identifier that I don't recognize.

I originally noticed something strange when I uninstalled the game Age of Empires Online, and noticed that the folder on the target drive was still there with all its data. So, I ran the `DIR` command to see if I the symlink was still active, it was. I thought it unusual but paid it no mind, and deleted the symlink as I normally would. I ran the command again, and it was still there with a similar identifier to that seen in the demo.

I am running Windows 8.1 Preview and noticed it has a new kernel, 6.3. I wondered if it was something new with NTFS, but have been unable to find anything.

Is there a way to completely remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the folders were in my Recycling Bin, and were renamed to that $XXXXXXX format. Emptying the bin got rid of them.